# ExtensionAttribute does not have accessor method getXYZ in class

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes, magento2.3.6

currently i'm facing the Problem that an extension attribute wont work as expected.
On our test setup i get the Property has no accessor Error, while my local setup runs fine.

> Message: Property "SaveInCompanyAddressBook" does not have accessor method "getSaveInCompanyAddressBook" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface"

The attribute is configured in the extension_attributes.xml and after a compile all files including the necessary code are generated.

> cat customer/module/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="save_in_company_address_book" type="integer" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

> cat generated/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/AddressExtensionInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * ExtensionInterface class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface
 */
interface AddressExtensionInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface
{
    /**
     * @return integer|null
     */
    public function getSaveInCompanyAddressBook();

    /**
     * @param integer $saveInCompanyAddressBook
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSaveInCompanyAddressBook($saveInCompanyAddressBook);
}
```

> cat generated/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * Extension class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface
 */
class AddressExtension extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject implements AddressExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * @return integer|null
     */
    public function getSaveInCompanyAddressBook()
    {
        return $this->_get('save_in_company_address_book');
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $saveInCompanyAddressBook
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSaveInCompanyAddressBook($saveInCompanyAddressBook)
    {
        $this->setData('save_in_company_address_book', $saveInCompanyAddressBook);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Both setups are using the same version of Magento 2.3.6

The interesting part: when i delete the cache unter var/cache the attribute works on time. After the creation of the cache files it stops working and i get the error again.

Maybe one has an idea that could help me solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code?

Comment: I added the relevant parts.